# get css element with space selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a structure below that I need to get the value of the tag between>

For example

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath (u '//span[contains(text(),"name")]')
```

HTML

```
<span itemprop="name">Colombia U20 vs Ukraine U20</span>
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question, I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following xpath.

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Colombia U20 vs Ukraine U20")]').text
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(.,"Colombia U20 vs Ukraine U20")]').text
```

OR

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@itemprop="name"]').text
```

If you want to use css selector try that.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('span[itemprop="name"]').text
```